# AJAX, PHP DB Lookup

Tags: php, ajax, database

Currently I have a form and when the user is entering data, this code calls another page to check if the username is in use. This is the code from the main page that calls the DB Page(test.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showHint(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  { 
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        if (xmlhttp.responseText.indexOf("green") != -1) {
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
        }
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

I want to change this so when it calls test.php it passes a value to test.php based on what form field the user is entering into.

That way I can use test.php to perform diffident DB lookups depending on the form field the user is completing.

Can anyone help ?
Thanks :)

Comment: Can you use some javascript library like jQuery? They have a wonderful AJAX function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I can, but I've no idea how :)

Answer (score 0):

An example with the Javascript jQuery ajax function. This function can be called whe user click on a component with id="myButton":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myButton').click(function() {

        var myValue = $('#myInput').attr('value');

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                myInput : myValue
            },
            dataType: "json"
        });

        request.done(function(msg) {
            alert( "Request done: " + msg);
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    });
});
```

With this example you can take the value from a texfield with **id = "myInput"** and pass it with a **GET** call to the **test.php** page.

In the test.php page you can take the value simply with:

```
$_GET['myInput'];
```

Just one tip: your test.php must return a [json](http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp) type.

Comment: Thanks :) How would I call this from multiple form fields ?

Comment: Thanks again :)
What I'm currently doing is a live name check as the user types into a form field. 
Doing this would require them to enter the name and the click a 'check' button ?? any way to do it as a live check ?

Comment: With my code: when someone enter a name and click the button (i wrote you the code) the page test.php is called with the name. Now you can do a php check and create a result in json format. If you appreciate my answer think about a vote or accepted answer.